# Is it possible to use `SqlDbType.Structured` to pass Table-Valued Parameters in NHibernate?

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, table-valued-parameters

I want to pass a collection of ids to a stored procedure that will be mapped using NHibernate. This technique was introduced in Sql Server 2008 ( more info here => [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) ). I just don't want to pass multiple ids within an `nvarchar` parameter and then chop its value on the SQL Server side.

Comment: Not that it's a bad question, but could you expand on why you want to do this?

Comment: Can SqlDBType.Structured be used for Table Value Parameters?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

My first, ad hoc, idea was to implement my own `IType`.

```cs
public class Sql2008Structured : IType {
    private static readonly SqlType[] x = new[] { new SqlType(DbType.Object) };
    public SqlType[] SqlTypes(NHibernate.Engine.IMapping mapping) {
        return x;
    }

    public bool IsCollectionType {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public int GetColumnSpan(NHibernate.Engine.IMapping mapping) {
        return 1;
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(DbCommand st, object value, int index, NHibernate.Engine.ISessionImplementor session) {
        var s = st as SqlCommand;
        if (s != null) {
            s.Parameters[index].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
            s.Parameters[index].TypeName = "IntTable";
            s.Parameters[index].Value = value;
        }
        else {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    #region IType Members...
    #region ICacheAssembler Members...
}
```

No more methods are implemented; a `throw new NotImplementedException();` is in all the rest. Next, I created a simple extension for `IQuery`.

```cs
public static class StructuredExtensions {
    private static readonly Sql2008Structured structured = new Sql2008Structured();

    public static IQuery SetStructured(this IQuery query, string name, DataTable dt) {
        return query.SetParameter(name, dt, structured);
    }
}
```

Typical usage for me is

```cs
DataTable dt = ...;
ISession s = ...;
var l = s.CreateSQLQuery("EXEC some_sp @id = :id, @par1 = :par1")
            .SetStructured("id", dt)
            .SetParameter("par1", ...)
            .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<SomeEntity>())
            .List<SomeEntity>();
```

Ok, but what is an `"IntTable"`? It's the name of SQL type created to pass table value arguments.

```sql
CREATE TYPE IntTable AS TABLE
(
    ID INT
);
```

And `some_sp` could be like

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE some_sp
    @id IntTable READONLY,
    @par1 ...
AS
BEGIN
...
END
```

It only works with Sql Server 2008 of course and in this particular implementation with a single-column `DataTable`.

```sql
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
```

It's POC only, not a complete solution, but it works and might be useful when customized. If someone knows a better/shorter solution let us know.

Comment: someone know about two column DataTable ?

Comment: Pawel Kupis - will you look at this similar but different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228253/sqldbtype-structured-to-pass-table-valued-parameters-in-nhibernate-to-select-wit

Comment: This approach has worked for me, but I run into the 2100 parameter limit if there are more than that many rows in the DataTable. Anyone else run into this? Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution than the accepted answer would be to use ADO.NET. NHibernate allows users to enlist `IDbCommands` into NHibernate transactions.

```cs
DataTable myIntsDataTable = new DataTable();
myIntsDataTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));

// ... Add rows to DataTable
ISession session = sessionFactory.GetSession();
using(ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    IDbCommand command = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedureName");
    command.Connection = session.Connection;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    var parameter = new SqlParameter();
    parameter.ParameterName = "IntTable";
    parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    parameter.Value = myIntsDataTable;
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);            
    session.Transaction.Enlist(command);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Could I attach the `parameter` to an `NHibernate.ISQLQuery`, rather than using ADO for the whole query? [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46244598/241211)

Answer (score 2):

For my case, my stored procedure needs to be called in the middle of an open transaction.
If there is an open transaction, this code works because it is automatically reusing the existing transaction of the NHibernate session:

```cs
NHibernateSession.GetNamedQuery("SaveStoredProc")
    .SetInt64("spData", 500)
    .ExecuteUpdate();
```

However, for my new Stored Procedure, the parameter is not as simple as an `Int64`. It's a table-valued-parameter (User Defined Table Type)
My problem is that I cannot find the proper Set function.
I tried `SetParameter("spData", tvpObj)`, but it's returning this error:

> Could not determine a type for class: …

Anyways, after some trial and error, this approach below seems to work.
The `Enlist()` function is the key in this approach. It basically tells the `SQLCommand` to use the existing transaction. Without it, there will be an error saying

> `ExecuteNonQuery` requires the command to have a transaction when the
>   connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction…

```cs
using (SqlCommand cmd = NHibernateSession.Connection.CreateCommand() as SqlCommand)
{
    cmd.CommandText = "MyStoredProc";
    NHibernateSession.Transaction.Enlist(cmd); // Because there is a pending transaction
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@wiData", SqlDbType.Structured) { Value = wiSnSqlList });
    int affected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Since I am using the `SqlParameter` class with this approach, `SqlDbType.Structured` is available.

This is the function where `wiSnList` gets assigned:

```cs
private IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> TransformWiSnListToSql(IList<SHWorkInstructionSnapshot> wiSnList)
{
    if (wiSnList == null)
    {
        yield break;
    }
    var schema = new[]
    {
        new SqlMetaData("OriginalId", SqlDbType.BigInt),           //0
        new SqlMetaData("ReportId", SqlDbType.BigInt),             //1
        new SqlMetaData("Description", SqlDbType.DateTime),        //2
    };

    SqlDataRecord row = new SqlDataRecord(schema);
    foreach (var wi in wiSnList)
    {
        row.SetSqlInt64(0, wi.OriginalId);
        row.SetSqlInt64(1, wi.ShiftHandoverReportId);
        if (wi.Description == null)
        {
            row.SetDBNull(2);
        }
        else
        {
            row.SetSqlString(2, wi.Description);
        }

        yield return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a little extra code? I'm interested in what `wiSnSqlList` looks like. I am wondering whether I can use your approach to answer an old ([Roomba'd](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)) [question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46244598/241211).

Comment: @Michael Hi Michael I have added that function. Thanks for formatting my answer last time :-) SO newbie here...sorry that function is not formatted properly. I don't have time now though

Comment: @Michael the link to the old question/answer does not seem to be accessible from my side...

Comment: @Michael Yeah so my newly added sample code seems to fulfill what you need in that link. You can give it a try. Actually you can also pass in a Datatable instead of IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass collections of values without the hassle.

Example:

```cs
var ids = new[] {1, 2, 3};
var query = session.CreateQuery("from Foo where id in (:ids)");
query.SetParameterList("ids", ids);
```

NHibernate will create a parameter for each element.

Comment: Isn't there limitation of 2100 parameters? Besides, I don't think it's a solution for my need :) Or is it?

Comment: This is very slow when many parameters are used, bloats plan cache and breaks with more than 2100. Good for the simplest of cases, but useless for more serious usage.