# Is it possible to use a variable as a table name in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-insert

I am working on a legacy application using an Oracle 11g database and have come across an issue where I have 5 tables all in different schemas with the same data structure. I need to be able to insert data into these tables and I'm trying to avoid duplicate code.

I know do something like the following

```
IF p_schema = SCHEMA1 THEN 
  INSERT INTO SCHEMA1.TABLE_NAME_SCHEMA1 (...) VALUES (...)
ELSIF p_schema = SCHEMA2 THEN 
  INSERT INTO SCHEMA2.TABLE_NAME_SCHEMA2 (...) VALUES (...)
ELSIF p_schema = SCHEMA3 THEN 
  INSERT INTO SCHEMA3.TABLE_NAME_SCHEMA3 (...) VALUES (...)
ELSIF p_schema = SCHEMA4 THEN 
  INSERT INTO SCHEMA4.TABLE_NAME_SCHEMA4 (...) VALUES (...)
ELSIF p_schema = SCHEMA5 THEN 
  INSERT INTO SCHEMA5.TABLE_NAME_SCHEMA5 (...) VALUES (...)
END IF;
```

Is there any way to make the table name a variable inside the SQL so that I can just make one insert statement, but insert into the table I want?

Comment: Please describe your efforts and results so far.

Answer (score 3):

Can you?  With dynamic SQL, sure.  Should you?  With just 5 tables, I'm not sure that the extra complexity of dynamic SQL is worth it.

```
p_sql_stmt := 'INSERT INTO ' || p_schema || '.TABLE_NAME (<<columns>>) ' ||
              '  VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ... ? ) ';
EXECUTE p_sql_stmt
  USING val1, val2, val3, val4, ... , valN;
```

If you are doing this sort of thing all commonly (rather than looking at one piece of code that has this ugly `IF`), assuming that you have a basic OLTP application, so that you're doing lots of single-row inserts where the overhead of triggers isn't going to be terrible, I'd probably consider creating a view that does a `UNION ALL` of the 5 tables along with an identifier that tells you which table the data comes from and an `INSTEAD OF` trigger that directs the `INSERT` to the proper table.  Then all your other code could just reference the one view rather than having the `IF` statement all over the place.  Something like

```
CREATE VIEW composite_view
AS
SELECT 'Schema1' schema_name, a.*
  FROM schema1.table_name a
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Schema2' schema_name, b.*
  FROM schema2.table_name b
...
```

And in the `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger

```
IF( :new.schema_name = 'Schema1' ) 
THEN 
  INSERT INTO schema1.table_name( <<columns>> ) 
    VALUES( :new.col1, :new.col2, ... );
ELSIF( :new.schema_name = 'Schema2' ) 
THEN 
  INSERT INTO schema2.table_name( <<columns>> ) 
    VALUES( :new.col1, :new.col2, ... );
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `insert all` or `insert first` for this.  Something like:

```
INSERT FIRST
    WHEN p_schema = 'SCHEMA1' THEN INTO SCHEMA1.TABLE_NAME_SCHEMA1( . . . )
    WHEN p_schema = 'SCHEMA2' THEN INTO SCHEMA2.TABLE_NAME_SCHEMA2( . . . )
    . . .
     . . .;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **dynamic sql**:

```
declare 
   schema_name varchar2(50);
begin
   v_name := 'SCHEMA1'; -- set the value of schema, you can do it in a loop also
   execute immediate
      'INSERT INTO '||schema_name ||'.TABLE_NAME_SCHEMA1 (...) VALUES (...)';
   commit; 
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to deal with this problem is to use procedure, which usage shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5868320/1739325)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE employeeType AS OBJECT (employeeId INT, employeeName VARCHAR2(50));
-- this is how you can use variables
CREATE TYPE ttEmployeeType AS TABLE OF employeeType;

CREATE PROCEDURE testCustom (pLocation ttEmployeeType)
AS
BEGIN
        INSERT
        INTO    employee (emp_id, emp_name)
        SELECT  *
        FROM    TABLE(pLocation);
END;
```