# SqlDbType.Structured to pass Table-Valued Parameters in NHibernate to select without a :param?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, nhibernate, table-valued-parameters

I want to pass a collection of IDs (via table-valued parameter) to an NHibernate `IQuery` `select` statement to be used in a join:
In native SQL, I can do this (SQLSelectData below). Notice there is no `:param` in the `SqlCommand` sql:

```cs
public static bool SQLSelectData()
{
    string conACME = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                           .AppSettings["conACME"].ToString();
    DataTable tblBusUnit = new DataTable();
    tblBusUnit.Columns.Add("VALUE", typeof(int));
    DataRow dRow = tblBusUnit.NewRow();
    dRow["Value"] = 1;
    tblBusUnit.Rows.Add(dRow);
    dRow = tblBusUnit.NewRow();
    dRow["Value"] = 6;
    tblBusUnit.Rows.Add(dRow);
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conACME))
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
         "select bus_unit_id, BusUnit " +
         "from BusUnit b " + 
         "join @tvpBusUnit s on s.value = b.BUS_UNIT_ID;",
         con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(
        new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@tvpBusUnit",
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured,
            TypeName = "dbo.[DLTableTypeInt]",
            Value = tblBusUnit
        });
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            string stBusUnitId = rdr["bus_unit_id"].ToString();
            string strBusUnit = rdr["BusUnit"].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Bus Unit:" + strBusUnit);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

How do I do this in **NHibernate?**  I tried the accepted solution of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701364/is-it-possible-to-use-sqldbtype-structured-to-pass-table-valued-parameters-in) by using the `Sql2008Structured` and `Structured2008Extensions` classes.

See code below that calls the `SetStructured()`:

```cs
public void SQLSelectTVP<T>()
{
    objNSession = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession(strConn);
    DataTable tblBusUnit = new DataTable();
    tblBusUnit.Columns.Add("VALUE", typeof(int));
    DataRow dRow = tblBusUnit.NewRow();
    dRow["Value"] = 1;
    tblBusUnit.Rows.Add(dRow);
    dRow = tblBusUnit.NewRow();
    dRow["Value"] = 6;
    tblBusUnit.Rows.Add(dRow);
    StringBuilder sbSQL = new StringBuilder();
    sbSQL.Length = 0;
    sbSQL.Append("select bus_unit_id, Business_Unit " +
                 "from tblBUSINESS_UNIT b " +
                 "join @tvpBusUnit s on s.value = b.BUS_UNIT_ID");
    IQuery sqlQuery = objNSession.CreateSQLQuery(sbSQL.ToString());
    sqlQuery.SetStructured("tvpBusUnit", tblBusUnit);
    var lstQR = sqlQuery.List<T>();  

}
```

However, it errors because there is no `:param` in the SQL:

> Parameter tvpBusUnit does not exist as a named parameter in [select bus_unit_id, Business_Unit from tblBUSINESS_UNIT b join @tvpBusUnit s on s.value = b.BUS_UNIT_ID]

How can I fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I'm not sure what you mean by "there is no :param in the sqlcommand sql."

Comment: Look at the error message in bold just below.

Comment: Have you tried putting `@` in `sqlQuery.SetStructured("tvpBusUnit", tblBusUnit);`? Did you also mean to put `inner join` in the sql statement?

Comment: yes.  It also gives an error.  The issue is no parameter is in the sql just the table valued parameter (@tvpBusUnit):  "select bus_unit_id, Business_Unit from tblBUSINESS_UNIT b join @tvpBusUnit s on s.value = b.BUS_UNIT_ID"

Answer (score 1):

From the link you posted, I think the way you are accessing the structured variable is incorrect.

```cs
s.CreateSQLQuery("EXEC some_sp @id = :id, @par1 = :par1")
 .SetStructured("id", dt)
```

Your code does not use the `:id` part, that is, `:tvpBusUnit`.

Also note that the `TableType` (in `TypeName`) may have to be created on the DB beforehand. Please check if this is required. From your code:

```
TypeName = "dbo.[DLTableTypeInt]",
```

Some discussion on passing table value parameters is provided here but NHibernate has an update without having to create types like this:
[Passing table valued parameters to NHibernate](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3736). But this may need a pull-request. The answer provided in the other post you referred to allows you to create such types, one for each `TableType`.

Comment: The data for `@tvpBusUnit` needs to be passed to nhibernate to an sql query (NOT a stored procedure). The first example that uses straight sql works and passes the data for `@tvpBusUnit`.    Is there a way to mofidy setStructured code to pass for this condition.

Comment: @Remy, Yes I meant it for sql query. It is for stored procedures that you don't use the **:X** format. For raw sql query, you will need the **:X** format. Sorry for the delayed reply... Hope this helps.
I can advise you to create a table value parameter inside the sql and then assign it using the :X format. I did this for a XML parameter that I passed like: `.SetParameter("Ids", sb.ToString(), NHibernateUtil.StringClob)` and set it in the SQL like this: `SET @IdsXml = :Ids;`

Comment: @Remy, for stored procedures, the input parameters are clear from the definition of the stored procedure, but for raw sql queries, there is no standard way of providing input values. NHibernate seems to allow this using the :X format. This is my understanding - did not read this somewhere.

Comment: @Remy, or anyone else, if this answer works for you... can you please mark it as so? That will help others also and confirms it for me too. Thanks!