# How can I get NHibernate to make a multicolumn table-valued parameter?

Tags: nhibernate, table-valued-parameters

I'd like to pass a two-column table-valued parameter (TVP) to an `ISQLQuery`:

```cs
var sql = @"
    INSERT INTO MovieRatings (PersonID, MovieID, Score)
    SELECT :personID, o.movieID, o.score
    FROM :scoreObject o";
var query = session.CreateSQLQuery(sql);
query.SetInt32("personID", fred.ID);
query.SetParameterList("scoreObject", fredsRatings.Select(r => new {
        movieID = r.Movie.ID,
        score = r.Score
    }).ToArray() /*, Optional IType hint here */);
query.ExecuteUpdate();
```

When I do this (or try to hint the `IType` as `NHibernateUtil.Object` or `NHibernateUtil.Class`), NHibernate complains:

> `NHibernate.HibernateException` : Could not determine a type for class: `` <>f__AnonymousType5`2[[System.Int32],[System.String]] ``

It also complains if I try to make a `struct` with properties for `movieID` and `score` and make an array of those instead of anonymous objects. The only thing that changes is the type it "could not determine."

Microsoft seems to say that [a TVP can have whatever columns you want](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters#passing-a-table-valued-parameter-to-a-parameterized-sql-statement):

> ### Passing a Table-Valued Parameter to a Parameterized SQL Statement
>
> The following example demonstrates how to insert data into the `dbo.Categories` table by using an `INSERT` statement with a `SELECT` subquery that has a table-valued parameter as the data source. When passing a table-valued parameter to a parameterized SQL statement, you must specify a type name for the table-valued parameter by using the new [`TypeName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.typename) property of a [`SqlParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter). This `TypeName` must match the name of a compatible type previously created on the server. The code in this example uses the `TypeName` property to reference the type structure defined in `dbo.CategoryTableType`.
>
> ```cs
> // Assumes connection is an open SqlConnection.  
> using (connection)  
> {  
>     // Create a DataTable with the modified rows.  
>     DataTable addedCategories = CategoriesDataTable.GetChanges(  
>         DataRowState.Added);  
>     
>     // Define the INSERT-SELECT statement.  
>     string sqlInsert =   
>         "INSERT INTO dbo.Categories (CategoryID, CategoryName)"  
>         + " SELECT nc.CategoryID, nc.CategoryName"  
>         + " FROM @tvpNewCategories AS nc;"  
>     
>     // Configure the command and parameter.  
>     SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(  
>         sqlInsert, connection);  
>     SqlParameter tvpParam = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(  
>         "@tvpNewCategories", addedCategories);  
>     tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;  
>     tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.CategoryTableType";  
>     
>     // Execute the command.  
>     insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();  
> }
> ```

Is there a way to convince NHibernate to make a TVP with named columns? I'd like to avoid [writing my own `IType`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3806983/241211).

Answer (score -1):

Remondo has [a novel solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54707903/241211) to this problem: Add the TVP definition to the transaction with a `SqlParameter` from the Microsoft library.

Edit to follow with sample code for the query in the question.