# How to access columns and data of a Sql parameter of SqlDbType as Structured in C#?

Tags: c#, datatable, table-valued-parameters, sqlparameter, sqldbtype

In C#, for Table-valued parameter I add a SqlParameter with 'SqlDbType' as 'Structured' and 'Value' as a C# DataTable.
I want to extract this data later in my code.

1. I want to verify if the SqlDbType/DbType is 'Structured'.
2. If yes, and if the 'Value' is a 'DataTable', I want fetch the columnNames of its Columns and the data in the DataRows.

Below is the code for SqlParameter.

```
DataTable memoIdDt = new DataTable();
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter ("memos", SqlDbType.Structured) { Value = memoIdDt, TypeName = "Table_Type_In_DB" };
```

Later I want to do something like the below (this is not the exact code).

```
//I am not able to use param.SqlDbType. I can use the param.DbType property.
//But it returns Object. So, not able to get the if clause right.
If(param.DbType == SqlDbType.Structued)
{
    //foreach column in param.Value.Columns, print columnNames
    //foreach DataRow in param.Value, print the array
}
```

Please help if you know how this can be achieved.

Comment: Does `param.DbType == SqlDbType.Structured` work?  If it does, the first part of your question is already answered, but you have to test it to see if it does.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3701364

Comment: @RobertHarvey This doesn't work. That was just a pseudo code, I have found one workaround to fetch the value, then type, then name, but can't get to use the DbType or SqlDbType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simply cast `param.Value` back to a `DataTable`:

```cs
if (param.SqlDbType == SqlDbType.Structured)
{
    var table = param.Value as DataTable;

    foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns) Console.WriteLine(column.ColumnName);
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) Console.WriteLine(row.ItemArray.Length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, only concern is the if clause validation. I can't use SqlDbType. I can use the DbType property, but it returns Object.

Comment: Why can't you use the SqlDbType property? If it's because you have something with a static type of IDbParameter or DbParameter then just cast that to SqlParameter first which is almost certain to be a valid cast if you are creating it originally as said type

Comment: @Sini why can't you use SqlDbType? If you define param as SqlParameter (as in your code snippet), then it should be available for you?